Pycharm tensorflow libraries importing error
i have tried to install the current version of tensorflow bt still it gives error in importing "Model","Tokenizer","Sequence" i have failed to know the problem,i am using PyCharm but in Collab it was well run
i tried importing tensorflow libraries ,i expected to gives no error as i have already installed the tensorflow in my IDE "PyCharm"

I had the same issues with PyCharm and tensorflow. I had to install it with pip via terminal. PyCharm wasn't able to install tensorflow.
how to install tensorflow Check the docu and use the appropriate version for your system. OS, CPU and GPU are important here
